# External command line program to concat files

Tags: windows

I need concat 2 files, it can be easily done using
copy file1+file2 mergedfile

However, I need to use an external windows command line program to do it, not the internal "copy" command. Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just use the program that offers the `copy` command:

```
cmd /c copy file1+file2 mergedfile
```